# App esperar resposta do AlertDialog para password

Tags: android, alertdialog

A função a baixo retorna uma senha digitada no `AlertDialog` e está em uma classe responsável por criar qualquer caixa de diálogo no meu app, porem como todo `AlertDialog` o app não "espera" o retorno da função para continuar a execução. Minha duvida é: como fazer o app esperar o retorno da função para continuar a executar o resto do código?

```
    public String pass() {
    final String[] result = new String[1];

    final EditText txtUrl = new EditText(activity);

    // Set the default text to a link of the Queen
    txtUrl.setHint("digite a senha");

    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setTitle("Senha")
            .setMessage("Digite a senha para liberar o acesso")
            .setView(txtUrl)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    result[0] = txtUrl.getText().toString();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            })
            .show();
    return result[0];
}
```

Comment: Existe [esta](https://github.com/mauricioj/gals/blob/master/GalsM/src/br/ufscar/sigam/util/ModalDialog.java) classe, que faz exatamente isso, mas entretanto não é uma boa prática, não recomendo usar. O java é diferente por exemplo do C# e outras linguagens, você pode passar um `listener` para sua função.

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13761/2541). Caso não queira utilizar um DialogFragment(recomendo que use), veja o Fragment como sendo a sua classe e o método `onAttach()` como sendo o seu construtor.

Comment: @ramaral poe um exemplo de DialogFragment como resposta assim posso positiva-lo

Comment: Você compreendeu o que está na outra resposta? Se sim e for isso que procurava eu voto esta pergunta como duplicata da outra. Lembre que você sempre pode votar em qualquer resposta/pergunta, se achar que ela lhe foi útil.

Comment: Sim entendi e também fis algumas pequisas a partir da informação passada la. Pode marcar como repetida. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

E se você chamar a próxima função só quando o usuário der o OK?

Exemplo:

```
.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    result[0] = txtUrl.getText().toString();
                    activity.someFunction();

                }
            })
```

Comment: Infelizmente não posso fazer assim, o pedido de senha ocorrerá somente quando o desconto for superior a um limite e o código posterior a ele deverá ser executado sempre a senha é somente para permitir esse desconto ou retorna-lo ao valor padrão